# Update SQL only on selected columns

Tags: c#, sql

I building edit menu in C# to edit SQL rows in the database but I want the user to be able to choose which column in the particular row to update  to update  if they left the box empty I don't want to update that column. for example

the user sees three boxes he can enter something into one box that would reflect updating only one column in the row, rest of the columns would stay as they were. I started implementing something like this

```
string RowUpdate ="";
if(Title !="" && Author =="" && Pages==""){
RowUpdate = "Update BookTable set Title=@Title where BookID=@ID";
}
else if (Title =="" && Author !="" && Pages ==""){
RowUpdate = "Update BookTable set Author=@Author where BookID=@ID";
}
```

when logic is completed the Correct SQL will be picked,
as you can see this type of logic for only 3 text boxes take 9 different outcomes and it scales exponentially as edit rows would grow.

I don't know if that even possible but is there a way to update an only particular column if there was no value entered so I don't have to write huge logic to update only particular column?

something like

```
 RowUpdate = "Update BookTable set (IF null Skip Title=@Title),(If null Skip   Author=@Author), (If null Skip Pages=@Pages) where BookID=@ID
```

or any other way to do this simpler and quicker?
thank you for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but hope that it will fulfill what you need to do. It will create query on the basis of value available.

```
string rowUpdate = "UPDATE BookTable SET ";
if(Table != "")
rowUpdate += "Table=@table ";
if(Author != "")
rowUpdate += "Author=@author ";
.
.
rowUpdate += "WHERE BookID=@ID ";
```

Comment: This is similar to my solution but thank you, while I still need to implement all the logic this looks like it's less writing

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to default the properties to their old values if they're not chosen to be updated? This would allow you to do a full row update on all the properties, and it would only truly change the updated ones while setting the unedited ones to the same values as before.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use a combination of [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) in your SQL to write a single UPDATE statement.

First, let's create a temp table to play with:

```
CREATE TABLE #mybooktable
(
    BookID int not null IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title nvarchar(50),
    Author nvarchar(100),
    Pages int
)
GO
INSERT #mybooktable (Title, Author, Pages) VALUES ('ABC','Mary B.',10)
INSERT #mybooktable (Title, Author, Pages) VALUES ('DEF','John D.',20)
GO

SELECT * FROM #mybooktable
GO
```

Here's the query. COALESCE will pick the first non-null value. NULLIF will force an empty string to return null.

```
-- variables
DECLARE @bookId int, @title nvarchar(50),  @author nvarchar(100), @pages int

-- Some test parameters. Going to only change the title here
SELECT @bookId = 1, @title = 'ABC'

UPDATE #mybooktable SET
    Title = COALESCE(NULLIF(@title,''), Title),
    Author = COALESCE(NULLIF(@author,''), Author),
    Pages = COALESCE(CASE WHEN @pages <= 0 THEN NULL ELSE @pages END, Pages)
WHERE BookID = @bookId

-- check
SELECT * FROM #mybooktable
```

Run this block and mess with the test parameters. Only the parameters that you've defined will change.

- I stuck a CASE statement in the Pages because I'm assuming you've already cast it to an int.
- You'll need to TRIM() your strings to remove spaces